Api calls not working after ssl certificate addition
I have a web app that uses angular as client, springboot for microservices and mysql as db. a couple of days ago i have added a domain to the site and today i used lets encrypt to create an ssl certificate.
the project is runing on an ubuntu VM with docker compose
reverse-proxy file for the domain below.
server {
    server_name full_domain_name;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://local_ip:4200/ ;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate 
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/full_domain_name/fullchain.pem; # managed by 
    Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key 
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/full_domain_name/privkey.pem; # managed by 
    Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by 
    Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
    if ($host = full_domain_name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;  # HTTP
    server_name full_domain_name;
    return 404; # Managed by Certbot
}

the thing is after upgrading to https, the api calls stopped working.
error on client console: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
error in microservice: 2024-11-23T20:06:54.862Z  INFO 1 --- \[event\] \[nio-8081-exec-1\] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name \[(characters)\]. HTTP method names must be tokens

i tried updating api calls to use http instead and (of course) it wouldnt work:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://full_domain_name/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://full_domain_name:8081/api/endpoint'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I also tried to have nginx as a separate service in docker compose and specify the nginx.conf file in the project but that just overcomplicated everything

In case someone stumbles on this post having the same problem, this is what i did: the api calling methods have to be changed into something like https://full_domain_name/service_name
where that "service_name" will be used to redirect the request to the app that runs internally on the vm
reverse-proxy config file below:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name full_domain_name;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/full_domain_name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/full_domain_name/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/; # Points directly to the Angular app running on the VM
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /security/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/; # Internal route for SECURITY microservice
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api/event/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/api/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api/main/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/api/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
   if ($host = full_domain_name) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }

   listen 80;  # HTTP
   server_name full_domain_name;


   return 404; # Managed by Certbot
}

where, for example, /api/event is based on that "service_name" i mentioned earlier.
in my case, if the client does a request to
https://full_domain_name/api/event/getAll
the nginx reverse-proxy will forward this request to
http://localhost:8081/api/getAll
basically the requests are still being done securely but nginx handles that security instead of having to configure each application to do that
